# struct node{ int data; node *r_child; node *l_child; node parent; }; why node parent get error..Please help me

Tags: c++

```
struct node{
  int data;
  node *r_child;
  node *l_child;
  node parent;
};
```

Why node parent line get error? please help me
Error message(field 'parent' has incomplete type 'node')

Comment: Needs to be a pointer.

Comment: What is the error message? That would motivate more people to answer.
You can't put the same struct inside a struct. That would might cause the node struct size to grow infinitely.
node { .... node { .... node{ ... infinite nodes } } }
Which of course limited memory can't withhold.